# Add an image to header of Enfold theme

Tags: wordpress, header, custom-headers, tenfold

I've a WP site with the Enfold-child theme. For the header, I choose to place the company logo upper left and main menu under the company logo. I would like to add an image on the right of the company logo but I don't try to do this.
Last part of header.php is the following

```
<?php 
    if(!$blank) //blank templates dont display header nor footer
    { 
         //fetch the template file that holds the main menu, located in includes/helper-menu-main.php
         get_template_part( 'includes/helper', 'main-menu' );

    } ?>

    <div id='main' class='all_colors' data-scroll-offset='<?php echo avia_header_setting('header_scroll_offset'); ?>'>

    <?php 

        if(isset($avia_config['temp_logo_container'])) echo $avia_config['temp_logo_container'];
        do_action('ava_after_main_container'); 

    ?>
```

Have I to modify this file to add the image? Can you help me, please?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try this. It's a Knowledgebase article from Enfold detailing how to add a Widget area to the header for adding custom code, ie an image.

It's what we use to do exactly that.

: http://www.kriesi.at/documentation/enfold/adding-a-widget-area-to-the-header/

Answer (score 1):

if you do not want to touch the header.php you may consider using a css ::after selector